# How to add a drop shadow to dc.js bar chart rects

Tags: css, d3.js, dropshadow, dc.js

how can i add a drop shadow to a dc.js bar chart?

I've looked at svg filters but not sure how i could apply that to a dc.js chart. I've been looking at http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394 example to add drop shadow defs but cant see how you can add the defs to the chart rect.bars.

I'm pretty new to d3.js etc so any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: That depends on the chart I guess. Which one are you thinking about?

Comment: Hi Lars. Ideally i'd like to apply it to all of them really but for now the dc.barChart and dc.rowChart

Comment: Well, you would have to create a filter like in the example and apply it to all the elements.

Comment: To clarify: you don't add the `<defs>` element to the rectangles, `<defs>` stores the definition of the filter, then you use the `<rect>` filter style attribute to reference the filter id, as shown in @DJ Martin's example.  Since the filter doesn't change with the code, you can even predefine the filter in the HTML markup file and add it to the rectangles with CSS. If you don't want to change your markup or CSS, another simplified approach is to store the filter code as a string variable that you then add to the graphic with `svg.append("defs").html(filterCode)`: http://jsfiddle.net/kWYY4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of applying a filter to a dc chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/5Lvcq/

I simply added the code that Lars referred to after the dc.renderAll().

First retrieve the chart svg:

```
 var defs = rowChart.svg().append("defs");
```

Next define the filter:

```
var filter = defs.append("filter")
        .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
        .attr("height", "150%")
        .attr("width", "200%");

    filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
        .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
        .attr("stdDeviation", 5)
        .attr("result", "blur");

    filter.append("feOffset")
        .attr("in", "blur")
        .attr("dx", 5)
        .attr("dy", 5)
        .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

    var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

    feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "offsetBlur");
    feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
```

Finally, apply the filter to the rows:

```
    rowChart.selectAll("rect")
        .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");
```

Hopefully the example at http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/5Lvcq/ helps you get going.

Comment: Looks great, although you might want to make the filter height and width somewhat larger to avoid the sharp cut-off of the blurred shadow: height 150% width 200% looks good even on the small bar.  Unfortunately, you can't define filter dimensions as `100% + 20px`, which is more logical for this type of effect.